# How does NSApplicationMain find the main nib file?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, xib, nib

[The documentation for the `NSApplicationMain` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/1428499-nsapplicationmain) says that it

> loads the main nib file from the application’s main bundle

It's suggested on the web that `NSApplicationMain` finds "the main nib file" by looking at the `Info.plist` file at the key `NSMainNibFile` (obfuscated by XCode as "Main nib file base name"), i.e. `NSApplicationMain` does something like

```
let mainBundle: Bundle = Bundle.main
let mainNibFileBaseName: String = mainBundle.infoDictionary!["NSMainNibFile"] as! String
mainBundle.loadNibNamed(mainNibFileBaseName, owner: myApp, topLevelObjects: nil)
```

But if I delete the `NSMainNibFile` key, the application still finds and loads my `MainMenu.xib` file! And then if I rename the file to `Foo.xib`, the application instead finds and loads `Foo.xib`!

**What is the real search procedure that `NSApplicationMain` uses to find "the main nib file"?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the key `NSMainNibFile` is missing, `NSApplicationMain` calls `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:nil owner:application]` which calls `[mainBundle pathForResource:nil ofType:@"nib"]` which returns the first nib file it finds.

Comment: Great concise clear answer, thanks! For reference: [`load​Nib​Named(_:​owner:​options:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1618147-loadnibnamed) and [`path(for​Resource:​of​Type:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1410989-path)

Comment: I'm a bit confused because `load​Nib​Named(_:​owner:​options:​)` does not allow `nil` as the first argument. Is this behavior documented?

Comment: No, but Objective-C doesn't mind. [loadNibNamed:​owner:​](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsbundle/1402904-loadnibnamed) is deprecated.

Comment: @jameshfisher Why do you want to fight the framework at all costs? if `load​Nib​Named(_:​owner:​options:​)` doesn't support `nil` Apple is going to protect the developers against themselves ;-)